# Remove newlines using shell command (must work in a KDE global shortcut)

Tags: text-processing, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, plasma5

I need a shortcut to strip newlines from the text in the current selection. I want to put my command into a KDE global shortcut, which I already know how to do. The command I came up with is:

```
sh -c 'xclip -o -sel p | tr -d "\-\n"  | tr "\n" "\ " | xclip -sel c; xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v'
```

That is intended to take the current selection and pipe it through `tr` to remove end-of-line hyphenation (and join the fragments), then replace the remaining newlines with spaces, then put this onto the clipboard and paste it (where ever the focus is).

**The problem: it is not replacing newlines with spaces** `tr "\n" "\ "`. Instead of doing that, it replaces newlines with nothing. I tried all kinds of representations of a space, and none of them work

I tried `xdotool type`, but that eats all whitepace and runs everything together even without the use of `tr`.

I would prefer to use the selection (primary or secondary) instead of the clipboard, and to not have to use `xdotool key ctrl+v` if possible. Even better if I can avoid `xdotool` entirely due to the unexpected way it handles whitespace in my experience.

I do not have `xvkbd` installed and I prefer not to install it. However, if it will help, I can install [copyq](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/copyq/), [python-pyperclip](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/python-pyperclip/), or [xorg-xclipboard](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xorg-xclipboard/). I can also consider other tools in the main Arch repos.

Comment: Is this not acceptable? `| sed 's/\\n/ /g'`

Comment: @cutrightjm - the input is multiple lines, so that will not work unfortunately. sed works best on single lines, although with tags and branching it could possibly do what I'm trying to do. Didn't succeeed with that yet.

Comment: `tr -d "\-\n"` doesn't work the way you think it does. It deletes all hyphens and newlines, irrespective of whether they're together.

Comment: @muru - yes, I realized that. I have one answer now, but if you have a better one please post it and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
sh -c 'xclip -o -sel p | perl -p -e "s/-\n//g"|  tr "\n" " "| xclip -sel c; xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v'
```

I replaced the first `tr` with perl. I realized that `tr` was seeing the sequence `-\n` as two independent characters instead of a string.

I found the perl suggestion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7697604/463994

There's probably a way to do this with a single perl command, but I don't know it. I'll accept better answers.

EDIT: here's the **better solution**, thanks to Rakesh Sharma (see comments):

```
sh -c 'xclip -o -sel p | perl -pe "s/-\n// || s/\n/ /" | xclip -sel c; xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v; xdotool key Alt'
```

I added `xdotool key Alt` because I have the shortcut bound to an Alt key combo and that is required to clear the Alt key.

Comment: `perl -pe 's/-\n// || s/\n/ /' ` will replace your perl+tr into one invocation of perl.

Comment: @RakeshSharma - I'll use that. Thank you.

Comment: Almost the same: `sed ':a N; s/-\n//; s/\n/ /; ba'`.  The `N` command tells `sed` to read multiple lines into the pattern space (work buffer area), which is necessary to make the newlines accessible as ordinary characters, eligible to be substituted.  `:a`…`ba` creates a loop that reads ***all*** of the input into the buffer at once.  This still leaves a newline at the end (if there was one there already); add `| tr -d '\n'` if you want to remove that.